# How to make multiselect in dxi-column Angular devextreme?

Tags: angular, devextreme, devextreme-angular

Faced the problem of adding multiple selection options to dxi-column. It turns out to make a drop-down list in the column, but I need to have both a drop-down list and a check-box in one column.

I'm getting it right with the drop down list

```
<dx-data-grid
    [dataSource]="dataSource"
>
    <dxo-editing [allowAdding]="true" [allowDeleting]="true" [allowUpdating]="true"></dxo-editing>
    <dxi-column dataField="TEST_DATA" caption="TestData">
        <dxo-lookup [dataSource]="listData" valueExpr="testName" displayExpr="testLabel"></dxo-lookup>
    </dxi-column>
</dx-data-grid>
```

I can't even make two dropdown lists. Tried something like:

```
<dx-data-grid
    [dataSource]="dataSource"
>
    <dxo-editing [allowAdding]="true" [allowDeleting]="true" [allowUpdating]="true"></dxo-editing>
    <dxi-column dataField="TEST_DATA" caption="TestData">
        <dxo-lookup [dataSource]="listData" valueExpr="testName" displayExpr="testLabel"></dxo-lookup>
        <dxo-lookup [dataSource]="listData2" valueExpr="testName" displayExpr="testLabel"></dxo-lookup>
    </dxi-column>
</dx-data-grid>
```

But only listData2 value was displayed.

But I even need to make not two dropdown lists, but a dropdown list and a checkbox.
And all in one dxi-column.

Please help me! Thank you in advance!

Comment: The devextreme demo website provides an example of a tag box that offers a dropdown list + checkbox. Visit their [custom editors](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/CustomEditors/Angular/MaterialBlueLight/) section.